# How to send images with axios using flask-python?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flask, axios, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send an image using axios get method

I have tried the same using post request from axios

HTML

```
  <div>
    <form id="upImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file">
      <input type=submit value=Upload onclick="uploadImage()">
      </form>

  </div>

    function uploadImage() {

      let image = $('#file').get(0);
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', image.files[0]);
      axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "/imgUpload",  
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
          response_data = response.data["img_data"];
      });
    };
```

python

```
    @app.route('/imgUpload', methods=['POST'])
    def upload_image():
        file = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join('/home/user/images', filename))
        return return jsonify({"img_data":102})
```

This change of method from `post` to `get` gives empty file.

```
    function uploadImage() {

      let image = $('#file').get(0);
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', image.files[0]);
      axios({
        method: "get",
        url: "/imgUpload",  
        data: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
          response_data = response.data["img_data"];
      });
    };



  'KeyError: 'file' and file will be empty.
```

How to replicate the same process using get request from axios?

Comment: You cannot send a file with a GET request

Comment: as @Musa said, uploading files should have a **body** to be able to transfert files data through the request, and files are binaries wish should have its own **request representation contract** so that backend server, which will receive it, will be able to parse it as a "multipart" to make it ready for reception and processing as a file. In that case we are talking about POST method not GET one. you can check [this resource](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/)

Answer (score 1):

To send image, you have to use axios post http request and send the image data with the request. Although it's unclear from where you want your image to come from and where to upload. But this will be the axios post request code you will need to upload the image to your backend server and get a response.

```js
axios.post('/send_image',{file: 'test.jpeg'},{ headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }}
}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, How to read the file for passing into axios, The above form content is fine?

Comment: From where you want to take user input, do you have some website or something ?

Comment: Yes, From a form. I have added the sample form in the question above

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios/ This might help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, But how to upload and read an image

Comment: Where you have to read the image? on frontend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233655/discussion-between-user15590480-and-sanket-vyawahare).